# Evince crashes in Ubuntu 18.04 (fontconfig error)

Tags: server, 18.04, fonts, evince

Evince crashes every time i try to launch it on a recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 server:

```
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 272: 
mismatched tag
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 272: 
invalid attribute 'name'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 272: 
invalid attribute 'mode'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 272: 
invalid attribute 'target'
[1]    15320 segmentation fault (core dumped)  evince
```

I can successfully validate the file `65-fonts-persian.conf` with `xmllint --noout --dtdvalid fonts.dtd 65-fonts-persian.conf`.

The "problematic" section around line 272 is:

```
265         <!-- multiply the matrix to slant the font -->
266         <edit name="matrix" mode="assign">
267             <times>
268                 <name>matrix</name>
269                 <matrix><double>1</double><double>-0.2</double>
270                     <double>0</double><double>1</double>
271                 </matrix>
272             </times>
273         </edit>
```

The file `65-fonts-persian.conf` is not the only one causing problems - removing it makes fontconfig complain about `/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf`, removing that one passes the problem further to another file etc.

Apart from that, i don't have any problems with fonts or fontconfig.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!